# If my CentOS 7.2 box has vagrant 1.7.2, can I just run the 1.8.1 rpm to get vagrant 1.8.1?

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a CentOS 7.2 laptop.  I have VirtualBox 5.0.x installed on it.  Out of the box, it appears that I have Vagrant 1.7.2.  Apparently this doesn't support VirtualBox 5.0.x, but it appears that version 1.8.1 does.  What is the proper way to get access to 1.8.1?  There is an installation rpm for 1.8.1 that I've downloaded, I can run this with "rpm", but do I have to do anything else before I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Software Collections to get Vagrant 1.8.1 on CentOS: [Vagrant 1.8 by Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/sclo-vagrant1/) (the linked page contains instructions on how to do that). That will give you a build tested by the CentOS project.

As a sidenote: If you downloaded a standalone RPM package (presumably directly from the Vagrant project) and wish to install it, do it using the `yum` package manager, not `rpm` -- `yum` takes care of dependencies.